# XML Schema Validation of XElement

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, linq-to-xml

I am working with multiple `XElement` objects to provide some user-specified data for several objects in my library.  I'm trying to avoid specifying the structure of the entire XML file because the library shouldn't care what the entire XML looks like as long as the specific elements it needs are structured correctly.

To that end, I have 3 separate `XSD` files that define schema for each of the 3 `XElements` my class needs, however I am running into some problems validating the XElement against the schema.  There doesn't appear to be a method to do that without a workaround.

From the MSDN page, the [`XElement.Validate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb349001.aspx) extension method appears to be geared to re-validating sub-elements of a larger file.  The `XmlSchemaObject` argument is causing my problems as I cannot assume it will be present in any of the `XElements`.  I think I can work around this issue by grabbing the `XmlSchemaElement` from my `XmlSchemaSet` to pass as the `XmlSchemaObject` argument, but since the `XmlSchemaSet` already defines everything, it seems strange to have to do that.

Is there a better option for validating an `XElement` with a schema without first validating the entire `XDocument`?

Or should i just let the business layer handle the schema validation in the application and let the library assume the `XElement` is properly formed (I considered this option, but as a personal preference prefer to avoid throwing exceptions and would rather just let the calling method know that the `XElement` is invalid via a return parameter).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I understand the problem you have with the provided API, as far as I see it you have two options, one being to put your `XElement` into an `XDocument` with e.g. `XDocument doc = new XDocument(xElementToValidate);` and then to call [the `Validate` method on that `XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340331.aspx) where all you have to pass in is the `XmlSchemaSet`, the second option being the way you outlined yourself, namely to use the `Validate` method of the `XElement`, making sure you pass in the `XmlSchemaSet` and the root element definition in that schema set as the `XmlSchemaObject`. If these are simple schemas with just one top level element definition all you have to do is e.g.

```
    XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schemaSet.Add(null, "schema.xsd");
    schemaSet.Compile();

    XmlSchemaObject schemaObject = schemaSet.GlobalElements.Values.OfType<XmlSchemaObject>().First();
```

If you wrap one of the two approaches into a method then it shouldn't be any more effort than calling a similar convenience method the .NET framework could have supplied.

Comment: I have no idea why i didn't think of wrapping the code in my own `XElement.Validate()` extension method.  Seems so logical now that you say it.  Creating an `XDocument` is another good idea that should have occurred too me (I spent too much time trying to find out how to convert it, and i missed the obvious solution).  I'll experiment with both and see which I prefer.